# flask_swagger_ui can't load resources in cPanel server

Tags: python, flask, cpanel

anyone ever met this problem?

> In local development, the swagger doesn't have any problem, and the bundle is exist.
> [local log console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK5B7.png)
>
> But in cpanel server, the bundle ins't defined like this
> [cpanel log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ywBZ.png)

I'm walking on community for about 2 days and still stuck in this :')

> The entire route are fine and return 200 status, but the '/api/docs' is just like white blank screen.